# If you had to choose, would you rather go without luminance or chrominance?

Tags: images

We are learning image processing in computer vision course. There is [question](https://www.google.com.pk/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=go%20without%20luminance%20or%20chrominance&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=opera&hs=rLv&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=%22go%20without%20luminance%20or%20chrominance%22&oq=%22go%20without%20luminance%20or%20chrominance%22&gs_l=serp.3...33319.33768.1.34045.2.2.0.0.0.0.224.224.2-1.1.0...0.0...1c.Cms12gQXUPs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=6b3cbd7c7aeea059&biw=1218&bih=940) given in slides that "If you had to choose, would you rather go without luminance or chrominance?"

So on which information we can compromise, luminance or chrominance and why?

*If this is not the right place to ask this question, please redirect.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a premonition that it leads to the subject of “lossy compression” techniques ;), so I'll say “I'd rather loose some chrominance”. Why? Because human eyesight is “better” at spotting luminance than chrominance (we are able to see more precisely “brightness” changes than “color” changes – it goes with the way retina is built). Proof? Check out some articles about e.g. JPEG image format and see how much information is “thrown away” from chrominance vs. luminance, yet the image still “looks good”.

Answer (score 1):

I would also go without chrominance. This is because luminance is more important and plays a major role when we see an image. We were comfortable seeing black and white pictures but we can't have pictures with inappropriate intensity of colors in it.